# spring roo frontend twitter-bootstrap integration

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, spring-roo, frontend

I want to develop a pretty standard webproject with all basic functionalities such as landingpage, user registration, login and so on.

Since I'm familiar with Java and Spring, I set up the a project with Spring Roo including DBRE from an MySql database, MVC and Spring security.

Right now I'm wondering how to go on with the UI. I would like integrate a template from twitter-bootstrap and I already downloaded a working example project (no apache tiles structure). I'm not very familiar with Apache tiles and frontend design in general so my question is, what would be the best way to integrate it and bypass the standard CRUD design?

Is it only necessary to design a new default-layout and reuse existing .jspx files? Also is it possible to take the existing bootstrap.jsp template which uses sitemesh from the bootstrap-example as a new template and reuse existing .jspx files?

Reuse is important since there are still entities which will change in future. 
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally used twitter-bootstrap, but I am fairly familiar with the Spring Roo structure.

My first bit of advice would be to just simply not use their UI stuff.  Nothing says you have to generated your Controllers with scafolding, which takes the scafolded classes and auto-generates the CRUD methods and UI peices for you.  In fact, in my last 4 projects, I did all the UI coding myself (I still used Tiles w/JSPs, and let Roo make all the relavent tiles configs and resource bundles).  You can ALWAYS generate a plan Controller and use Roo for everything except the View pieces.

I don't see why you couldn't use the bootstrap.jsp you speak of.  The Tiles implementation is done using the [TilesViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesViewResolver.html), I believe, which should be configured in the application_context.xml (or whatever Roo calls the context XML file).  Just replace the TileViewResolver setup with something else.  I would suggest reading up on [Chapter 17.5 Resolving Views](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) in the Spring Reference guide.  I think for JSPs you want to use InternalResourceViewResolver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will give it a try and read the view Chapters. Without much experience in frontend development it would have been convenient to autogenerate as much as possible. However, it should be worth it, to get a proper understanding about that.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by plan controller? And does not scaffolding mean to implement all controllers, dao's and the UI methods by hand, or is there an other way?

Comment: Sorry "plain controller".  Scafolding is taking an Entity and auto-generating the CRUD Controller for that.  You are not locked into anything with Roo, so if you still want to use Scafolding to generate the JSPs and then edit them, you can.  There are tutorials out there to walk you through customizing the Roo-generated JSPs.  I am not big on Dojo (prefer jQuery), and I don't like some of the components Roo uses, so I have taking to using Roo to wire all the Model and Controller pieces, plus all the web security base framework, then writting my own View pieces.

Comment: Thats kind of what I think I'm going to do. Good to get some insights about best practices. Thanks

Comment: Well, IMO, as long as you limit the scope of your Controllers, use a Service layer for your business logic, and dont out any business logic in your View, I think you are good.  You will want to determine first how you plan to "wire" things together.  For instance, are you doing form POST/reply, where each page is a form, you post the data, get a new page.  Or are you doing more RESTful stuff, or AJAX, or some other mechinism.  Determine that first, then start coding it.